# Regular Expression - match all except next to newline

Tags: regex

I've run into an interesting situation. I've been given a flat file of data that has numerous line breaks throughout the fields. The only thing that has been provided that is helpful is that there has been an *additional* delimiter placed at the end of every row, right before a newline.

Because of this, I have been able to utilize a regular expression that matches all newlines NOT next to a delimiter - which in most cases, correctly removes new lines in the text fields, and not the newline denoting a new row.

```
[^|](\r\n)
```

Yes, we are using | as the delimiter.

The only problem with this approach is that it also gets rid of the first character to the left of the newline, when I simply want to get rid of the newline. **How do I write a regular expression that matches any newline NOT next to a | character, while only matching the newline itself?**

Comment: add the delimiter after the grouping like `[^|]+|`

Comment: What language are you using the regex in? Lookarounds could be useful here.

Comment: @nickb I'm just using the find/replace tool from notepad++ (replacing with an empty string)

Comment: @logan_gabriel - my answer works in Notepad++. Let me know if you need anything else. Just make sure you select "Regular Expression" in the search mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This positive lookbehind works in Notepad++ (just make sure you have Regular Expression selected in the Search Mode section of the dialog):

```
(?<=[^|])(\r\n)
```

This will match a carriage return/newline sequence that is followed by any character other than a pipe, but it will not match the character.